# overlap not working using JavaScript in Phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am making a game and in this game I want when the player overlaps with the coin, the coin disappears, but its not for some reason and I don't why. I have tried a lot of ways even putting the coin into a tile when I made the map but even then it still doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out please?

```
 var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', { 
 preload: preload, create: create, update: update, render: render });

 function preload() {
game.load.tilemap('level12', 'res/level12.json', null, 
Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
game.load.image('sprite12', 'res/sprite12.png');
game.load.spritesheet('dude', 'res/player.png', 64, 64);
game.load.spritesheet('droid', 'res/droid.png', 32, 32);
game.load.image('starSmall', 'res/star.png');
game.load.spritesheet('coin', 'res/coin.png',32,32 );
game.load.image('background', 'res/sprite3.png');

}

var map;
var tileset;
var layer;
var player;
var facing = 'left';
var jumpTimer = 0;
var cursors;
var jumpButton;
var bg;
var coin;


function create() {
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
game.stage.backgroundColor = '#000000';


bg = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'background');
bg.fixedToCamera = true;

map = game.add.tilemap('level12');
map.addTilesetImage('sprite12');
map.addTilesetImage('coin');
map.setCollisionBetween(1, 12);
map.setCollisionByExclusion([ 13, 14, 15, 16, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51 ]);

layer = map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1');
layer.resizeWorld();

coin = game.add.group();
coin.enableBody = true;
coin.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
createcoin();


game.physics.arcade.gravity.y = 200;

player = game.add.sprite(150, 900, 'dude');


game.physics.enable(player, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;


player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;



player.animations.add('left', [3,2,1,0], 10, true);
player.animations.add('right', [4,5,6,7], 10, true);


game.camera.follow(player);

cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
jumpButton = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);


game.physics.arcade.overlap(coin, player, killcoin(), null, this);

}
function killcoin(coin,player) {

coin.kill();
}



function  createcoin() {
coin = game.add.sprite(50,700, 'coin');
}

function update() {

game.physics.arcade.collide(player, layer);

player.body.velocity.x = 0;

if (cursors.left.isDown) {
    player.body.velocity.x = -150;

    if (facing != 'left') {
        player.animations.play('left');
        facing = 'left';
    }
}
else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
    player.body.velocity.x = 150;

    if (facing != 'right') {
        player.animations.play('right');
        facing = 'right';
    }
}
else {
    if (facing != 'idle') {
        player.animations.stop();

        if (facing == 'left') {
            player.frame = 0;
        }
        else {
            player.frame = 5;
        }

        facing = 'idle';
    }
}

if (jumpButton.isDown && player.body.onFloor() && game.time.now > jumpTimer) {
    player.body.velocity.y = -250;
    jumpTimer = game.time.now + 750;
}
}

function render () {



}
```

Comment: Well this line is wrong for sure `game.physics.arcade.overlap(coin, player, killcoin(), null, this);`

Comment: @Musa is it player.physics.arcade.overlap(coin, player, killcoin(), null, this);

Comment: The callback part is what I'm looking at.

Comment: idk i still dont know what to do

Comment: `killcoin()` should be `killcoin`

Comment: tired it still doesnt work

Comment: Well, I didn't say it would fix the problem, just that that line was wrong.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide your JSON file so that we can try to debug this? Or can you otherwise provide a minimal version?

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems in your code. First of all the naming of the variables is confusing. You're creating a group and assigning it to `coin` but you're also adding new sprites and assigning them to `coin`. So then what is the value of `coin` when calling the overlap function? Maybe this works correctly on a technical level, but just to avoid any confusion I would use different variable names for different things. If nothing else it makes your code more readable.

Secondly, the coin sprites that are added to the game in `createcoin()` aren't added to the group. And because it is not added to the group, the physics body of the sprite is never enabled.

Finally, the `arcade.overlap` function is called only once in create(). I think it should be called in the update() function. The update() function in Phaser.js is kind of the main game loop. It is called for every frame update.

So put those three fixes all together and I would try something like this:

```
grpcoins = game.add.group();
grpcoins.enableBody = true;
grpcoins.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;
//..

function  createcoin() {
    var c = game.add.sprite(50,700, 'coin');
    grpcoins.add(c);
}

function update() {
   //..
   game.physics.arcade.overlap(player, grpcoins, killcoin, null, this);
   //..
}

function killcoin(pl, cn) {
    cn.kill();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in create function you creating, in update function you updating, killing a coin is not initial state, it is something what is about to happen in certain conditions, these two lines

```
game.physics.arcade.overlap(coins, player, killcoin, null, this); //killcoin is callback so no(), coins with "s" as you are calling the whole group
function killcoin(coin,player) {
    coin.kill();
}
```

belongs to update function.
You might still have a problem with the scope.

also you should create group for coins, something like this, and you creating them so they go to create function

```
        coins= game.add.group();// group of many coins
        coins.enableBody = true;
        for (var i = 0; i<12; i++){
            var coin = coins.create(i*70,0, 'coin');// var individual coin
            coin.body.gravity.y = 6;
            coin.body.bounce.y = 0.7 +Math.random()*0.2;
        }
```

Also camelCasing is an excellent addition to your style, as it improves readability(killCoin, createCoin...)